# Theorem numbering: use dash instead of period

Tags: formatting, numbering, theorems, amsthm

In the following code, my theorem head looks like this:

**1.1 Theorem**

I want it to look like this:

**1-1 Theorem**

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{theorem}
{1em} % Space above
{} % Space below
{\itshape} % Body font
{} % Indent amount
% Indent amount: empty = no indent; \parindent = normal paragraph indent
{\bfseries\itshape} % Theorem head font
{} % Punctuation after theorem head
{1em} % Space after theorem head
% Space after theorem head: { } = normal interword space; \newline = line break
{\thmnumber{#2\hspace{0.375cm}}\thmname{#1}\thmnote{ (\normalfont\textit{#3})}} % Theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Any other improvements to this code are welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Immediately after creating the theorem, change the way the theorem number is displayed via a `\renewcommand`:

```
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\thechapter-\arabic{thm}}
```

Here is a complete minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{theorem}
{1em} % Space above
{} % Space below
{\itshape} % Body font
{} % Indent amount
% Indent amount: empty = no indent; \parindent = normal paragraph indent
{\bfseries\itshape} % Theorem head font
{} % Punctuation after theorem head
{1em} % Space after theorem head
% Space after theorem head: { } = normal interword space; \newline = line break
{\thmnumber{#2\hspace{0.375cm}}\thmname{#1}\thmnote{ (\normalfont\textit{#3})}} % Theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\thechapter-\arabic{thm}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\begin{thm}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```